# Why is my margin binding not updating the margin of my control?

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I have a text box that has a UserControl that will either appear/disappear depending on what the user types. The UserControl is just a simple pop-up with some options.

The XAML in my TextBox control for the pop-up is:

```
<local:CustomPopUp HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                   VerticalAlignment="Top"
                   DataContext="{Binding PopupVM}"
                   Margin="{Binding PopupMargin, Converter={local:StringToMarginConverter}}"
                   Visibility="{Binding PopupIsOpen, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVis}}" />
```

The DataContext and Visibility bindings are working correctly and the popup shows but the Margin binding does nothing. I have breakpoints inside the StringToMarginConverter but they are never hit.

If I set the margin to a value rather than use binding `Margin = "100,200,0,0"` then it works - when the popup is displayed, the pop-up is offset from the left-hand side and the top by the margin values.

The PopupMargin property is in the ViewModel for the textbox (same as the PopupVM and PopupIsOpen properties) and is:

```
public string PopupMargin{ get; set; } = "0,0,0,0";
```

I have tried to set the new value of the property at various stages but nothing seems to trigger the margin to update.

I'm fairly new to C# and WPF, so may just be missing something simple. I could just set it the margin in code behind but thought this was a better way of doing it.

Although the StringToMarginConverter is never run, this is the code:

```
class StringToMarginConverter : BaseConverter<StringToMarginConverter>
{
    public override object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string[] indVals = value.ToString().Split(',');
        Double.TryParse(indVals[0], out double left);
        Double.TryParse(indVals[1], out double top);
        Double.TryParse(indVals[2], out double right);
        Double.TryParse(indVals[3], out double bottom);


        return new Thickness(left, top, right, bottom);
    }

    public override object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

**EDIT:**

After reviewing, I noticed that the Visibility binding also wasn't working so I thought I'd add the XAML for the TextBox as this may be causing the issue.

I copied most of this from an example I found somewhere as it seemed to do what I wanted:

```
<TextBox x:Class="MyProject.CustomTextBox"
     xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
     xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
     xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyProject" 
     TextWrapping="NoWrap" 
     Foreground="#00000000"
     Name="MainTextBox"
     Text="{Binding DocText, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
     PreviewTextInput="TextBox_PreviewTextInput"
     SelectionChanged="MainTextBox_SelectionChanged">
<TextBox.Resources>
    <local:BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolToVis" True="Visible" False="Collapsed" />
</TextBox.Resources>
<TextBox.Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:CustomTextBox}">
        <Setter Property="AcceptsReturn" Value="True" />
        <Setter Property="AcceptsTab" Value="True" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Disabled" />
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Helvetica" />
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="9pt" />
    </Style>
</TextBox.Style>

<TextBox.Template>
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:CustomTextBox}">
        <!--Visual-->
        <Border Background="White" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <local:DrawingControl Grid.Column="0" ClipToBounds="True" />

                <Line Grid.Column="1" Margin="2,0,5,0" Stroke="Gray" StrokeThickness="1" Y2="1" Stretch="Fill"
                        StrokeDashArray="1,1" RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased" />

                <Grid Grid.Column="2">
                    <!--Render canvas-->
                    <Grid Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                        <local:DrawingControl ClipToBounds="True"
                                TextOptions.TextRenderingMode="ClearType" TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Display" />
                    </Grid>
                    <!--Transparent input textbox-->
                    <ScrollViewer Background="#00FFFFFF" />

                    <!--Custom Popup Control-->
                    <local:CustomPopUp HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                       VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                       DataContext="{Binding PopupVM}"
                                       Margin="{Binding PopupMargin, Converter={local:StringToMarginConverter}}"
                                       Visibility="{Binding PopupIsOpen, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVis}}" />

                </Grid>

            </Grid>

        </Border>


    </ControlTemplate>
</TextBox.Template>
```

Comment: PopupMargin Setter does not do NotifyProperyChanged. See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/how-to-implement-property-change-notification

Comment: The ViewModel is of type ViewModelBase (```public class OpenFileItemViewModel : ViewModelBase```) which handles all the property changed events. i don't set ```OnPropertyChanged``` on any properties and the rest all bind correctly.

Comment: They Set Correctly ONE TIME using the Default Value. Ok breakpoint the Converter, does it hit? BaseViewModel may handle events, but its is the job of each Setter to call Notify when value changes.

Comment: The BaseViewModel handles the notify event. I have many other properties in lots of different ViewModels and they all update the UI correctly, all done the same way.

Comment: I have just gone back and checked, and it turns out the Visibility binding isn't working either. But since the ViewModel to the CustomPopup is cleared, it effectively collapses and is almost not visible. So, the binding of the DataContext works, but not the display elements.

Comment: I'll update my question with the xaml from the textbox. Maybe it's something wrong in there.

Comment: Dont know what you meant by that, but if you see that data is being set correctly but the UiElements show stale state. That's classic evidence for not doing NotifyPropertyChange